# Changing legend label in googleVis charts

Tags: r, googlevis

**How do you change the default legend labels in a `googleVis` chart?**

*What I have tried*

I see there is a `labelInLegend` setting, and I can hardcode the options see below:

```
  library(data.table)
  library(googleVis)

  test.dt  <- data.table(day = c(1,2,3), value = c(0.8,1.2,1.2), 
                         price = c(1,1.1,1.2), name = c("A","A","A"))


  # set chart options in hamfisted hardcoded way
  testop <- list(series = "[{labelInLegend: 'A price'},
                            {labelInLegend: 'A value'}]",
                 legend = chart.op$op.legend)

  testplotdatay <-  c("price", "value")

  plot(gvisLineChart(test.dt, 
                     xvar = "day",
                     yvar = testplotdatay,
                     options = testop))
```

to get:
 [image: GoogleLinechartLegend]

*But how do you make this work in a **parameterised way**?*

Do you still need to send in JSON string into googleVis [as this old answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14080844/4606130), or is there now an easier way? For example, [googleVis](https://github.com/mages/googleVis/blob/master/R/gvis.R) now supports data roles (for AnnotationText, scope).

*The task*

I am looking to add the name in front of the numeric fields plotted to distinguish when more than one company will be selected e.g. A price, B price in the legend.

```
mylabels <- paste(unique(test.dt$name), testplotdatay) 
# i.e. "A price" "A value"
```

I have tried to send to googleVis with no luck:

```
testop <- list(labelInLegend  = mylabels)
```

or

```
testop <- list(series.labelInLegend  = mylabels)
```

**What do more seasoned googleVis users do?**

And, If I have to use `toJSON()` to parameterize what is right syntax?

EDIT: googleVis 0.5.9, R 3.1.3